# Pandas: Keep Column, Count, Drop Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to drop duplicates according to two columns, but count the duplicates before they are dropped. I've managed to do this via

`df_interactions = df_interactions.groupby(['user_id','item_tag_ids']).size().reset_index() \
 .rename(columns={0:'interactions'})`

but this leaves me with

```
   user_id  item_tag_ids  interactions
0      170            71             1
1      170           325             1
2      170           387             1
3      170           474             1
4      170           526             2
```

It does what I want with respect to counting, adding as a column and dropping the duplicates but how would I do this with retaining the original structure (plus a new column). Adding more to `groupby` changes its behaviour.

Here is the original structure, I only want to group by IDs:

```
   user_id  item_tag_ids  item_timestamp
0   406225          7271      1483229353
1   406225          1183      1483229350
2   406225          5930      1483229350
3   406225          7162      1483229350
4   406225          7271      1483229350
```

I would like to have the new `item_timestamp` field in the smaller dataframe to contain the first occurring timestamp for that combination.

Comment: What was the original structure?

Comment: @micric I'm trying to retain a column, `item_timestamp` after duplicate removal. So basically group by these IDs, count the interactions (duplicates before removal), add `item_timestamps` after duplicates are removed.

Comment: @kuomi understand that we cannot help you if you dont include example of original data before `groupby`.

Comment: From your Original structure what is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `transform` like the following to keep your original data's shape.

And to get a list of the values of all the item_stamps you can use `groupby` in combination with `agg(list)`

```
# First we create count column with transform
df['count'] = df.groupby(['user_id', 'item_tag_ids']).user_id.transform('size')

# AFter that we merge our groupby with apply list back to our original dataframe
df = df.merge(df.groupby(['user_id', 'item_tag_ids']).item_timestamp.agg(list).reset_index(), 
              on=['user_id', 'item_tag_ids'], 
              how='left',
                  suffixes=['_1', '']).drop('item_timestamp_1', axis=1)

print(df)
   user_id  item_tag_ids  count            item_timestamp
0   406225          7271      2  [1483229353, 1483229350]
1   406225          1183      1              [1483229350]
2   406225          5930      1              [1483229350]
3   406225          7162      1              [1483229350]
4   406225          7271      2  [1483229353, 1483229350]
```

**Explanation** of `.agg(list)` it aggregates the values of the group to a list like the following:

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'item_tag_ids']).item_timestamp.agg(list).reset_index()
Out[39]: 
   user_id  item_tag_ids            item_timestamp
0   406225          1183              [1483229350]
1   406225          5930              [1483229350]
2   406225          7162              [1483229350]
3   406225          7271  [1483229353, 1483229350]
```

Comment: Apologies, I've attached the original structure to my question

Comment: I can transform the size but this drops the rest of the columns, I want the `item_timestamp` to also have their duplicates dropped but if I group by all three, I get a different size of structure as some timestamps repeat

Comment: Editted answer, is this what you want? @kuomi

Comment: This seems to retain the original structure, but add a count. What I'm looking for is to group by the first two columns and then get the timestamps for what is remaining. The grouping trims my dataframe from 236268 to 31548 so what I'm looking for is the associated timestamps for each index in the new dataframe.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I want a grouping of unique user_id, item_tag_ids combinations but a counter of how many times duplicates appeared. I then want the first occurring timestamps for each of the unique combinations from the original DF

Comment: I think I understand what you want now, check edit. @kuomi

Comment: Your solution is actually far more useful than one I just tried as it retains the timestamps for each count, this is great. Thank you very much.